# Threadpool in c++ using Boost Library

Tags: c++

I would like to write a multithreaded merge sort using threadpool and hence downloaded the boost library. I am newbie to c++ and has difficulty in understanding how to run the example programs given with the source. here is the source from where i downlaoded..  http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/  .... It is there in the Download section...Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A threaded version of merge sort is still probably going to be slower than the sort included with the standard library (Even though that sort is not threaded). Besides -- sorting can already handle billions of integers in less than a minute... Threading is probably better done at a higher level than your sorting algorithm. (You're welcome to try, however ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Another tool for managing threads would be [TBB Intel Thread Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org).
There you even already have an implementation of merge sort, see "tbb/parallel_sort.hpp"
(however this implementation is not very efficient as it needs minimum O(n) time independent of number of threads).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that particular threadpool library (b.t.w. it's not part of the Boost), but the general concept of threadpool is very simple. The class must have something like `enqueue(std::function<void()> fn);` interface and all you need is to wrap your function to get desired function object, which is usually done either with `std::bind` or lambda function. Threadpool will keep your function objects in a queue until it has an available thread to execute it; at that point it simply calls `fn()`. Regarding parallelizing sorting you can write a quicksort version, which lends itself very well for parallelization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

P.S. `std::function`, corresponding `std::bind`, and lambda functions are part of C++0x, you can find substitutes in Boost as well.

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP would be a better bet for your requirements that self-managed threads.  There's a merge sort example included in [this overview](http://geco.mines.edu/workshop/class2/examples/openmp/openmp.pdf).